# Можно ли как-то сохранить результаты ответов api?

Tags: json

Есть сервис который предоставляет платное API, посуточно.
Покуда ведется разработка проекта и оплачивать API на время разработки как-то накладно.

Есть ли какой-то сервис, который мог бы сымитировать это это api? Например, этому сервису в течении дня я буду отдавать ответы от платного API, он их запишет. И потом я смогу обращаться к этому сервису, а он мне будет выдавать записанные ответы..

Есть что-то подобное или бред?...

Comment: универсальных эмулятор создать проблематично, ведь он должен эмулировать правильную реакцию на параметры, которые присущи  только конкретному api. Так что вероятность, что такой готовый сервис существует очень мала.

Comment: Модульные тесты когда-нибудь писали? Моки использовали? По сути, вам нужен свой мок, который имитирует сервис. Данные можете как сгенерировать сами (или вручную ввести), так и сперва запросить из платного сервиса; потом запишите их, куда вам удобней - хоть в файл, хоть в БД. После чего обращаетесь к сервису-моку, он выдаёт эти данные.